# Cannot Access Webpage from Outside LAN

Tags: php, apache-httpd

I have a CentOS 6.0 web server running httpd, mysql, php, and Joomla 2.5. It has a static, public IP address. I can access the webpage (which is the Joomla management console) by IP address perfectly from inside the LAN.

I went home and tried to connect from behind my router and can't get to the webpage. I can ping and ssh to the server but can't pull the webpage with http. I'm using Chrome for my browser.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

This is the output of `iptables --list`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ftp,ssh,http,https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport sports ssh,http,https state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
```

Comment: You may not have configured Apache to allow remote connections. Or you might have a misconfigured firewall. Can you post your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: You should also check your allow/deny settings in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Comment: Can you telnet to port 80 on the web server from a remote location?

Comment: Yes, probably, but unfortunately apache configuration isn't my forte. I'd look for [allow/deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) and [listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directives. There may be others.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn  No, I cannot telnet to port 80.

Comment: Does that server have an interface with that public IP address. Or is there some form of NAT on an upstream firewall?

Comment: No NAT. Although come to think of it there is a firewall separating my subnet from the rest of the the LAN. I'll see if that is the issue and post back.

Comment: out of topic, you can extract important lines in a config file easily with grep: `grep -v "#" httpd.conf | grep -v "^\s$"`. That first eliminates commented lines and then empty (with only whitespace between start and end of a line) ones.

Comment: sorry, asterisk missing:   `grep -v "#" apache2.conf | grep -v "^\s*$"`

Comment: The problems seems to be at your firewall/router. Is there another router/firewall between the webserver and the internet? When you access the webserver from your LAN, do you use the public IP, or do you user the LAN IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple enough. There was a firewall in the way. The university I am at blocks TCP/80 without being explicitly allowed through. I moved the listening port to something above TCP/10,000 (which they do not block) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been years since I had a problem like this with Apache, but way back when, in the middle ages of the internet, we had to resort to trickery in situations like this.

The basic problem we had was the same.  I have a public IP fronting my network, and my Apache server uses a private IP on the LAN, and a loadbalancer was forwarding requests to the public IP back to a series of servers with private IPs.

Using tcpdump, we could see that our HTTP requests were making it to Apache, but Apache wasn't responding, because the requests were coming in to the "public IP", and Apache didn't think it should respond to those requests, because that IP wasn't in it's local interface table.

What fixed it for us was bringing up the public IP address as an IP alias to the loopback interface, with a /32 netmask.  `ifconfig lo0:1 <IP/32> up` as it were. This allowed Apache to believe that it should be responding to those requests.

You need to find out if your requests from the outside are even getting to your Apache.  If they're not even making it to the servers, then you need to look at firewalls/routers/acls.  If you see the requests with `tcpdump`, but *not* in Apache, then you need to look at `iptables`.  If you do see the requests in Apache, but Apache isn't responding to them, you should have information in the access_log and error_log that will give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Well, if he can ssh, then that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would like to see the output of this command at home:

```
nmap -p 80 <public ip of webserver>
```

If `nmap` says `filtered`, then there is an issue with some firewall. If `nmap` says `closed`, then there is an issue with the configuration of your webserver.

Apart from this, I found the output of `iptables --list` not very useful. The command

```
iptables --list --verbose
```

provides much more information. Look at the first rule for example. It seems, that all packets are accepted, but `--verbose` reveals the truth. You can also see, if packets have been dropped, with the help of rule counters.

I would try this command on your webserver next:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 dst port 80
```

in order to see if any packets arrive at your server. Make sure to use the appropriate device name here.